# how to get values from a group ofcheckboxes?

Tags: jsp, servlets, checkbox

i am trying to get values of checkboxes to insert them later on in database.
It is ok that unchecked checkboxes will not be sent to my servlet but the problem that i have when cheking more than one checkboxe it returns just the first I'am doing like that im my JSP:

```
<td><input type=checkbox id=\""+i+"\" name=cbo value=<%=object.getNom()+ object.getPrenom() %>  /> <%=object.getNom()+object.getPrenom()%></td>
```

And In the servlet the following:

```
String[] checkboxes = request.getParameterValues("cbo");
    System.out.println("operators checked are:" + checkboxes[i]);
```

Like you see I want to get all the values checked.
but if i check more than one only the first CB is shown in my servlet.

Thinks for help.

Comment: Here's an array tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html By the way element identifiers starting with a number is illegal in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `request.getParameterValues()` returns an array of values for multiple parameters with the same name found in the request.

If your request is OK, and by that I mean `action?cbo=val1&cbo=val2&cbo=val3` etc, then, after you submit the form to your servlet, `checkboxes` should be `["val1", "val2", "val3"]`.

First check your request.

And one question: the following is in a loop, right?

```
System.out.println("operators checked are:" + checkboxes[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the same id instead of a dynamic one, on click call a javascript function. Here you'll get an array if you do a `getElementByID()`.
Set this array into a hidden form variable and access it in your action.

Comment: This is not a solution. This is a workaround. The code he posted ought to work. He only accessed it wrongly.